# Excel VBA loop through column and insert rows based on cell value

Tags: excel, loops, insert, row, vba

**Hello!**

I am trying to build a code that loops through each cell in range C8:C3276 and inserts a new row below if the cell value is "Total".

Here is the code i have so far:

```
Sub Create_new_rows()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set rng = Range("C8:C3276")

For Each cell In rng

If ActiveCell.Value = "Total" Then
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

Nothing happens when i execute the code. I assume the code is built incorrectly as the macro runs (i get no error message), but without doing anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems I think. 1) You should loop backwards as otherwise you will skip rows as you are adding more rows, and 2) in your loop you should have referred to `cell` rather than the ActiveCell which is never set.

```
Sub Create_new_rows()

Dim rng As Range, r As Long

Set rng = Range("C8:C3276")

For r = rng.Count To 1 Step -1
    If rng(r).Value = "Total" Then
        rng(r + 1).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. I would really love to understand exactly how your code works. Would you care to give a short explanation? :)

Comment: Sure. It uses a count variable rather than a range so that we can step backwards, starting at C3276 and ending at C8. `rng(r)` is just the rth cell in `rng` - e.g. when r=1 then rng(1) is C8. That said, using the Find method would be more efficient than looping through every cell.

Comment: I figured that was the logic being applied - but better safe than sorry ;)
Efficiency is not required in this particular case, as it was just a one time use. Thanks again for your help.